# How to set the width of a row to be equal to width of TextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want the width of the row that contains the button and the text to have the same width as the Text Fields. Here is what I have tried:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(padding),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    TextField(
        value = email,
        onValueChange = { email = it },
        placeholder = {Text(text = "Email")}
    )
    TextField(
        value = password,
        onValueChange = { password = it },
        placeholder = {Text(text = "Pass")}
    )
    Row {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                start(email, password)
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Start",
                fontSize = 18.sp
            )
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Skip"
        )
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I expected:

[image]

Can I achieve that without setting fixed sizes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the 3 composable with a `Column` and apply an [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) to it using `Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` and then apply `fillMaxWidth()` to the `Row` with the `Button`:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)){

        TextField()
        TextField()
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            //Button + Skip Text
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you so much.